# handle unhandled exception

Tags: c#, exception

I have a Ria service to call logic code. I want to write try catch block in every logic function to provide ways to handle unhandeled exceptions.

```
try
{
//something
}
catch(BussinessException e)
{
//save e.info to database
}
```

But I don't want to write this block code everywhere in my logic, and I don't want to put the exception handling piece in RIA service since another type of service also call the logic.

Does anybody have a one-place exception handling solution for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off your history I am pretty sure this is C# so here is my take.

The best way to avoid the duplication would be to wrap your logic like this.

```
private static void ExecuteLogic(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch(BussinessException e)
    {
        //save e.info to database
    }
}
```

With this in place you can easily perform various operations that share the same error handling.

```
ExecuteLogic(
    () =>
    {
        // Do something...
    }
);
```

Comment: . Wanted to ask some one smart.. Could you extend IDispose for something like this also. Good idea bad idea thoughts?

Comment: @Kieran - I am sure you could extend IDisposable in an infinite number of ways. Can you tell me what the end goal you would desire?

Comment: Great! This is convinient and also fit in our stupid static logic class.

Comment: hey dude. thx for your response. I have been looking into idisposable a bit more and it is not as suited to this as i first thought...

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to log exception, as I can see from your example, you can subscribe to [AppDomain.FirstChanceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception.aspx). But you wouldn't be able to handle it. Oh. btw this event was introduces only in .NET 4 :(.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more conventional Object Oriented solution using Command Pattern.

```
public interface ICommand {
  void Execute();
}

public class BankAccountWebServiceCall: ICommand(){

  string name;
  int accountNo;

  public BankAccountWebServiceCall(string name, int accountNo) {
    this.name= param1;
    this.accountNo= accountNo;
  }

  //ICommand implementation
  public void Execute() {
    SomeWebService.Call(name, accountNo);
  }
}

public class WebServiceCaller {
  public void CallService(ICommand command) {
    try {
      command.Execute();
    } catch (SomeBusinessException ex) {
      //handle exception
    }
  }
}

public class WebServiceCallerTest {
  public static void CallServiceTest() {
    new WebServerCaller().CallService(new TwoParameterwebServiceCall("Igor", 12345));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a strong approach I would have used in the past but I've been moving to a more functional style with my code.

Comment: This is a great dependency injection solution!

Answer (score 0):

implement an IHttpModule

web.config:

```
<httpModules>
    ...
    <add type="Citiport.Web.Module.ErrorHandleModule" name="GlobalErrorHandler" />
    ...
</httpModules>
```

The Class:

```
public class ErrorHandleModule : IHttpModule
    {

        private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Citiport.Web.Module.ErrorHandleModule");

        public ErrorHandleModule()
        {

        }

        void IHttpModule.Dispose()
        {
        }

        void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.Error += new System.EventHandler(onError);
        }

        public void onError(object obj, EventArgs args)
        {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            HttpResponse response = ctx.Response;
            HttpRequest request = ctx.Request;

            Exception exception = ctx.Server.GetLastError();
            /* handling exception here*/
        }
    }
}
```

refer:http://code.google.com/p/citiport2/source/browse/trunk/CitiportV2_website/App_Code/Web/ErrorHandleModule.cs